# Listening socket event in useEffect does not get latest messages

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, components

I am working on a React Js announcements component that shows new announcements when pushed from the backend. I am using Socket IO for real time.

So my code looks like this :-

```
 const [ announcements, setAnnouncements ] = useState([])

 useEffect(() => {
    let socket = SocketIO.connect(ENDPOINT);
    setSocket(socket);

    socket.on("newAnnouncement", (message) => {
      setAnnouncements( [ message, ...announcements ] )
    });

    axios
      .get(getAnnouncementURL)
      .then((res) => {
        setAnnouncements(res.data.reverse());
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);
```

The problem in the above code is as I am listening to the event at the first render so the announcements array is empty. So for every new announcement the socket gets, this  `([ message, ...announcements ])` becomes `[ message ]` ( as announcements is empty ) and all my
previous announcements gets flushed and I see only the new messages

Comment: Try `setAnnouncements(prev => [ message, ...prev ] )`

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
setAnnouncements(prev =>  [ message, ...prev ] )
```